# PSQL Error: function does not exist

Tags: postgresql

I have made a function in postgres

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foobar(
    x TEXT,
    y TEXT,
    z REAL
) RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $func$
.
.
.
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When I do \df i get the following:

```
+----------+--------+------------------+------------------------+---------+
|  Schema  |  Name  | Result data type |  Argument data types   |  Type   |
+----------+--------+------------------+------------------------+---------+
| mySchema | foobar | boolean          | x text, y text, z real | normal  |
+----------+--------+------------------+------------------------+---------+
```

But when I try to use it I get [42883] ERROR: function foobar(text, text, real) does not exist. Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. The call I'm doing is:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE foobar(column1::text, 'hello'::text, 7.2::real);
```

To me it seems like the function exists and the types match, I'm struggling to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: You need to prefix it with the schema: `where "mySchema".foobar(...)`

Comment: That did the trick, thanks!

Comment: Note that a user requires the `USAGE` privilege on the schema (e.g. `public`) to execute a function. Otherwise you get a `function does not exist` error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name) mentioned in his comment, the solution is prefix the function with the schema.

```
Wrong:   SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE foobar(column1::text, 'hello'::text, 7.2::real);
Correct: SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE mySchema.foobar(column1::text, 'hello'::text, 7.2::real);
```

Comment: Note that `"mySchema"` and `mySchema` are two different names. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS